# Select changed records in the last 15 minutes date and time in two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to select the records changed in the last 15 minutes, will this work?

```
--Select changed records
USE PC

SELECT        
    PEOPLE_CODE, PEOPLE_ID, PEOPLE_CODE_ID, PREVIOUS_ID, 
    FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME
FROM
    PEOPLE
WHERE 
    REVISION_DATE >= getdate()
    --Also need to check for time
    AND REVISION_TIME >=  dateadd(minute,-15,getdate()) --Test record
ORDER BY 
    REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC
```

Comment: Why would 15 minutes ago always be today's date (or later)? If you are checking at 5 minutes past midnight you'll be disappointed.

Comment: what are the datatype of `REVISION_DATE` and `REVISION_TIME`?

Comment: @HABO I think that `REVISION_DATE` might be just the `DATE`. It's still wrong though, since it will if the query runs at `00:04:00.00` for instance

Comment: It runs every 15 minutes and selects records changed in the last 15 minutes. The date and time are in two different columns, so I think I need to select today and then the last 15 minutes

Comment: the types are
 [REVISION_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [REVISION_TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,

Comment: Use dateadd for both conditions.

Comment: What date does the time have? Since `REVISION_TIME` is a `datetime` it can't avoid having _some_ date. Sigh.

Comment: The date and time look like this in the query output, REVISION_DATE REVISION_TIME
2014-05-15 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:27:29.493
2014-05-15 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 12:14:07.700
2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 13:02:36.990
2015-02-02 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 10:34:45.820
2015-04-08 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 13:35:42.983

Comment: it looks like i can use WHERE REVISION_DATE >= dateadd(minute,-15,(REVISION_DATE + REVISION_TIME))

Comment: no, that was backwards, it looks like i can use WHERE (REVISION_DATE + REVISION_TIME) >= getdate()

Comment: @ERPise Would you care to try again? Your last comswer (Ansment?) seems to have lost the 15 minute window into the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were right there, just have to combine the date and time column values. You can do it with the implicit or explicit method. The advantage of the implicit is that its quick and easy to write. The advantage of the explicit option is that if the `REVISION_DATE` column were to ever have the time part populated with something other than `00:00:00.000`, or the `REVISION_TIME` have the date part populated with something other than `1900-01-01`, it will still work as expected.

**Implicit:**

```
USE PC

SELECT        
    PEOPLE_CODE, PEOPLE_ID, PEOPLE_CODE_ID, PREVIOUS_ID, 
    FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME
FROM
    PEOPLE
WHERE 
    (REVISION_DATE + REVISION_TIME) >=  dateadd(minute,-15,getdate())
ORDER BY 
    REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC
```

**Explicit:**

```
USE PC

SELECT        
    PEOPLE_CODE, PEOPLE_ID, PEOPLE_CODE_ID, PREVIOUS_ID, 
    FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME
FROM
    PEOPLE
WHERE 
    (dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, REVISION_DATE), 0) + dateadd(d, -datediff(d, 0, REVISION_TIME), REVISION_TIME)) >=  dateadd(minute,-15,getdate())
ORDER BY 
    REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC
```